# Need to add two control values in a form, Angular

Tags: angular

I need to write a method that adds two control values together. The control values are in a form. They are called ..
The output will need to show the .. and if there are any , these will need to be added to .

This is what I have tried so far -

```
private 
    }



    if );

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing that because your values are strings and they are being concatenated together. You need to convert the values to a number first. You can use `+` to do that.

```
let allTotalMiles = (+totalMiles) + (+milesRun);
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I needed to convert the values to numbers. Many thanks!